# What does *((unsigned char*) ... ) mean?

Tags: c++, pointers

since i am still not allowed to comment i will post this as a question.
Someone once posted this piece of code as an answer (it works and everything is fine) but i don't really get how that piece of code works.
The answer was related to converting bytes to a float.

> ```
> typedef unsigned char uchar;
>
> float bytesToFloatA(uchar b0, uchar b1, uchar b2, uchar b3)
> {
>     float output;
>
>     *((uchar*)(&output) + 3) = b0;
>     *((uchar*)(&output) + 2) = b1;
>     *((uchar*)(&output) + 1) = b2;
>     *((uchar*)(&output) + 0) = b3;
>
>     return output;
> }
> ```

I know how floats work and i understand that he is assigning the bytes from the first to the fourth with the char bits using the address of the float.
**What i don't understand is this part of code:**

```
*((uchar*) ... )
```

I would really appreciate an answer because i believe it will give me a much better understanding of pointers and casting!

Comment: He wanted to work with his float field one byte at a time. The key to doing that is to cast it to a byte, which decides the size of the field you're working with. Then he uses the * to obtain a reference to the field in the size he wanted. If he were to cast it do a short, then he would be setting 2 bytes when he does the * (dereference). If he were to cast it to an integer, he would be setting 4 bytes at a time. The most important thing to understand is that * obtains a reference on a field based on the size of the pointer type so the casting is very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start from the very beginning:

```
&output // the address of float variable 'output'

(uchar*)(&output) // take the address of 'output' and treat it 
                  // as it were the address of  unsigned char

(uchar*)(&output) + 3 // add to that address 3*sizeof(unsigned char) bytes
                      // which is 3 bytes

*((uchar*)(&output) + 3) // dereference that address so it becomes
                         // like a 'uchar' variable which lays at the
                         // address which we saw in the previous step

*((uchar*)(&output) + 3) = b0; // assign to it value of 'b0'
```

Answer (score 2):

`uchar` is a byte.
`uchar*` is a pointer to a byte.
`&output` is the address of the float `output`.
`(uchar*)(&output)` is the address of `output` casted as a address of a byte.
so, `*(uchar*)(&output)` is `output` as it if were a `uchar`.

Answer (score 1):

The &output but takes the address of the float. The (uchar*) but says "treat this as being the address of a uchar, not a float. The + x bit then calculates an address offset in terms of the size of a uchar, not a float.

Overall,read this as 'treat this address as being the address of an unsigned character (rather than a float) and return the character at (the number of uchars above) that address.

The example code you give is really not good practice - it makes certain non-portable assumptions about the size of a float.

The 'best practice' for this kind of casting is 'see if you can avoid doing it', if not, at least try and make sure it doesn't lead to undefined behaviour (by e.g. making invalid memory accesses).

Answer (score 0):

```
(uchar*)(&output)
```

This part cast the address of the float `output` to a `uchar`.

The `*` in `*(...)` is the dereference operator assigning the value of result to uchar `b0`, `b1`, etc...

Comment: *"The pointer(...) is the dereference operator"* Thats interesting, i always thought (pointer...) was dereferencing. What is the difference between those two?

Comment: My mistake, I meant to say that the `*` in the expression `*(...)` is the dereferencing operator. The `(...)` just serves to specify what you want to dereferenced (ie, putting the `*` there gets you the value of what is at that address. Putting the `(..)` specifies the address the `*` uses. I hope that helped!

Comment: Well i know that much^^ but i am confused why i can use the `*` before the `(...)`. Is there a difference between `(*...)` and `*(...)`. Because normally i always used `(*...)` to dereference something. For example `int* fruits[10] = {new int};` Then dereferencing via `(*fruits)[3]`